# Joomla add 3rd party component

Tags: javascript, php, html, joomla, svelte

I'm trying to include a **svelte** app to **Joomla** site by copy all files from **public** to Joomla local folder, and in Joomla, I've created an article with a script where I include this **index.html**

**Svelte output**

```
+---public
|   |   favicon.png
|   |   index.html
|   |   output.doc
|   |   
|   \---build
|           bundle.css
|           bundle.css.map
|           bundle.js
|           bundle.js.map
```

**Joomla script to include index.html**

```
{source}

<?php ini_set("include_path", "/var/www/vhosts/examplesite.com/httpdocs/files/forms/public"); ?>

<?php include 'index.html'; ?>

{/source}
```

Locally when I launch index.html from the public, all works fine, bun in Joomla noop.
The error is that Joomla can't find files from **build** folder, for example in **index.html** are included **bundle.css** like this:

```
<script defer src='./build/bundle.js'></script>
```

And I expected what full path for **bundle.js** will be:

```
https://www.examplesite.com/files/forms/public/bundle.js
```

but actually, the browser requires it from

```
https://www.examplesite.com/bundle.js
```

So, there is a problem with the path for all files from the **build** folder. Help !!!

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development, then you owe it to yourself to register an account on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange. Whenever you have a question that pertains to Joomla or would benefit from the support of volunteers who have an intimate understanding of Joomla and its extensions, then please ask it on JSE. We are not getting enough questions https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842/joomla

Answer (score 0):

if you do

```html
<script defer src='./build/bundle.js'</script>
```

the browser will indeed try to get it from the location you mentioned, this is because the `./` part indicates the *root* and makes it an absolute path.

Change your markup to:

```html
<script defer src='/build/bundle.js'</script>
```

to have it search the bundle files relatively to the current location.

Comment: I'm getting an error: Refused to apply style from 'https://examplesite.com/en/build/bundle.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.